# Alternate way to prove continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a proof for a continuous function. The argument goes that if we can prove $\forall {x_n} \rightarrow x$ and $\forall u$ if we can prove that if $f(x_n) \leq u \Longrightarrow f(x) \leq u$ $\forall n$ and $f(x_n) \geq u \Longrightarrow f(x) \geq u$ then $f(x)$ is continuous. I am having a hard time trying to understand this proof. As far as I know, we are supposed to prove that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ right? How is proving the above statement equal to proving this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's prove that your argument is equivalent to continuity. If $f$ is continuous at $x$ and $x_n \to x$ then obviously $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ and hence it is clear that if $f(x_n) \leq u$ for all but finite number of $n$ then $f(x) \leq u$ as well. Same goes for $f(x_n) \geq u$ implies $f(x) \geq u$.

Now the other direction. Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $x$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x)$. That means you can find $\epsilon>0$ such that:

$\forall (n_0 \in \mathbb{N})  \exists (n \geq n_0)[|f(x_n)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon]$

So for infinitely many values of $n$ we have $|f(x_n)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon]$, or equivalently for infinitely many values of $n$ we have either $f(x_n)\geq f(x)+\epsilon$ or $f(x_n) \leq f(x)-\epsilon$. So at least one of these two must happen for infinitely many values of $n$. Without loss of generality suppose infinitely many times we have $f(x_n) \leq f(x)-\epsilon$. Take the first $n$ that satisfies that and call it $n_1$. Take the second $n$ and call it $n_2$. And so on. You get a sequence $x_{n_k}$ which is a subsequence of $x_n$ and hence still converges to $x$. But now see: if you write $u=f(x)-\epsilon$ for all $k$ you have $f(x_{n_k})\leq u$ but $f(x)>u$. So if $f$ is not continuous then the condition you have is not satisfied.